# Using same GPIO pins simultaneously from two Python scripts using RPi.GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I have two different scripts. One is a Kivy app and another is a MQTT client script that subscribes to topics received from a web server. The same hardware connected to the GPIO pins can be used from the Kivy app or remotely from a web server.

I have extracted the GPIO code in a common file that both scripts import.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def GPIO_Setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW)

def doSomething(dt):
    GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Both scripts do the import as `import actions as Actions` and on initialise run `Actions.GPIO_Setup` and on the relevant user input / MQTT topic ping call `Actions.doSomething(x)`.

At script end both call `GPIO.cleanup()`. If one of the scripts crashes/exits will it clear out GPIO for the other script too?

Also if both try to use the same pin at the same time - will it cause a conflict / failure? If yes is using semaphores a valid option in this case?

Comment: "What would be the best way to ensure that only one of these scripts can access the same pins at a time?"  You are asking for opinions.  Please tell us what you mean by "best way"?  We can then see if our answers would meet your criteria.

Comment: RPi.GPIO warns you if you use the same pin, although you can ignore the warning. Proper code releases pins after use. Only you can determine the "best" solution.

Comment: @joan Hey guys - I've edited the question to hopefully be a bit more clear as to what are my concerns.